# Data is not added to existing node in database

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to add data to my database without any luck.
In my code i have made a button when click, it will add data to my users database but it will not add it to the user but it just add the data outside like this:

[image: why is the data not inside my user]

is it because you cant add data when you have use the createUserWithEmailAndPassword() function?

Can anyone please show me how it is done?

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function()
{

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user)
    { 
        if (user)
        {
            var massage = inputText.value;
            var ref = database.ref("Users");

            var data = {
                display: massage
            }
            ref.push(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you call `push()` Firebase generates a new unique ID. So to add the new data to the existing node, you should not call push. Instead you need to find a reference to the existing node for that user.

The easiest (and by far most common) way to do this, is to store the user data under the UID of each user.

```
Users
  kHD...NoS
    username: "bob"
```

Also note that there's no reason to put this type of `onAuthStateChange` listener inside a button click handler. Just attach it from the top-level JavaScript and it will trigger whenever the user signs in or when their auth state changes in any other way.

Alternatively, if the code really must run in response to the button click, there's no real use for a auth state listener and you can just check `firebase.auth().currentUser`:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser)
    {
        var message = inputText.value;
        var ref = database.ref("Users");

        var data = {
            display: massage
        }
        ref.child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).update(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are saying that i first need to create "display" in my user and update it. Because you can not just add data to the user list?

Comment: Nope, nothing like that. But every time you call `push()`, you're creating a new child. If you want to update an existing child, don't call `push()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct *if* you want to insert a new entry in Firebase database (just like your screenshot shows).

But, if you really want to *sign up* a new user, then you should be using `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` instead.

Finally, if you really want to *update* an existing node, see **Frank** response above ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try this.  you can change update to set.  In your case something like

`demo.update("users/KIK...fuA","display","my message");`

```
//REVEALED METHOD TO ADD NODES WITH DATA TO REALTIME DATABASE
//eg, demo.update('mynode','myKey','myValue')
var demo = (function() {
  var pub = {};
  pub.update = function (node,key,value){
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('/');
    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = value;
    ref.child(node).update(obj)
    .then(function() {
      console.log('Update Ran Successfully');
    });       
  }
  //API
  return pub;
}());
```