# Multiple Values Together in one child - Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save user info together in realtime firebase database, but it is not working as I expected.
This is my code to save to the DB

```
   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("FYP").push().child("Name").setValue(name);
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("FYP").push().child("Job").setValue(job);
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("FYP").push().child("Number").setValue(number);
```

In return I get 3 "unique" childs that hold one piece of data. What I want is for one child to hold all 3 pieces of information. Sorry if not explained perfectly. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: Also check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43560529/209103. "Whenever you call push() Firebase generates a new unique ID."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the link I provided in comments "". So to ensure you only get one new unique key, you should call `push()` only once:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push()
ref.child("FYP").child("Name").setValue(name);
ref.child("FYP").child("Job").setValue(job);
ref.child("FYP").child("Number").setValue(number);
```

Or (as a single operation:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push()
Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("Name", name);
values.put("Job", job);
values.put("Number", number);
ref.setValue(values);
```

The advantage of the latter is that it's a single write operation, so writing all the properties will either succeed of fail as one.

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin i used a hash map,i created a child and a push so each group of values got it's own personal id:The code looks like this :

```
val values= hashMapOf<String,String>()
values.put("text",findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etPost).text.toString())

values.put("image",downloadUrl!!)
                  
values.put("userUID",userUID!!)

myRef.child("post").push().setValue(values)
```

And this is the firebase output:
-MyxdijM9aEUMbMmP59T -> unique id for each push

image:
"some link" ->link of the image

text:
"what's up ?" ->text

userUID:
"U2z64GG7iPV2zCvhSicWpI1J" ->user id

**All of them in the same child**